# Is there a similar of MessageBox of ExtJS in ADF Faces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, extjs, oracle-adf

I'am looking for a possibility to achieve a MessageBox in ADF Faces. 
Is there a similar of MessageBox of ExtJS in ADF Faces?

Here is an example [msg-box](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html)

May be someone can direct me to the right way

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at `<af:popup>` and then use an `<af:dialog>` within it to get YesNo, OkCancel, YesNoCancel dialogs. Also you can add components like `<af:progressIndicator>` within an `<af:dialog>` to get the popup showing the progress.